# Question about use of "engage"

Tags: grammar

"Enterprises engaging in foreign trade" or "Enterprises engaged in foreign trade", which one is correct, thanks!

Comment: according to http://www.reverso.net/spell-checker/english-spelling-grammar/ they are both correct

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are correct and for all intents and purposes mean the same thing.

One might sound ever-so-slightly more appropriate depending on the context (e.g., "Enterprises engaging in foreign trade should (do xyz)" sounds slightly better than "Enterprises engaged in foreign trade should (do xyz)").

To be super-specific: "Engaging" is the progressive form, so it implies something that's ongoing. "Engaged" is the perfect form, so it implies something that's (in some sense) completed or the current state.